# Popup appearing on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, togglebutton

I want a popup to appear every time I hover a togglebutton. It then needs to stay open until I click somewhere else in the application. The code below works fine on start up but as soon as I check or uncheck the togglebutton the popup refuses to appear. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

The WPF code

```
        <ToggleButton Name="btnLogFile" Style="{StaticResource StandardToggle}"
                      Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,3,3,0" 
                      MouseEnter="btnLogFile_MouseEnter">
            <Path Margin="7" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Uniform"
                Stroke="{StaticResource TextLight}" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="Nonzero">
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 0 0 L 20 0 L 20 10 L 30 10 L 30 40 L 0 40 Z" />
                        <PathGeometry Figures="M 20 0 L 22 0 L 30 8 L 30 10" />
                    </GeometryGroup>
                </Path.Data>
            </Path>
        </ToggleButton>
        <Popup Name="popLogFile"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnLogFile}" Placement="Custom"
               HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0"
               MouseLeftButtonDown="popLogFile_MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource BackgroundDark}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}" BorderThickness="1"
                    Width="300" Height="Auto">
                <Grid Margin="3">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="22" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="22" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <TextBlock Margin="0,1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Foreground="{StaticResource TextLight}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">Directory</TextBlock>
                    <TextBox Name="logfilePath" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                             Style="{StaticResource StandardTextBox}"
                             Foreground="{StaticResource TextLight}">
                        C:\logfile.txt
                    </TextBox><!-- Button made invisible for the time being -->
                    <Button Name="btnBrowseLogfile" Style="{StaticResource StandardButton}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Visibility="Collapsed">...</Button>

                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </Popup>
```

And the togglebutton's mouse event:

```
    private void btnLogFile_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.popLogFile.IsOpen = true;
        this.popLogFile.StaysOpen = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Add event triggers to ToggleButton:

```
       <ToggleButton Name="btnLogFile" 
                  Style="{StaticResource StandardToggle}"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,3,3,0" >
        <ToggleButton.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="popLogFile" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames  FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                    KeyTime="00:00:00"
                    Value="True" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Checked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="popLogFile" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames  FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                    KeyTime="00:00:00"
                    Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ToggleButton.Unchecked">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard TargetName="popLogFile" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                        <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames  FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                            <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame
                    KeyTime="00:00:00"
                    Value="False" />
                        </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

        </ToggleButton.Triggers>

        <Path Margin="7" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Stretch="Uniform"
        ...
```

2)  Set in XAML StaysOpen="False" :

```
<Popup Name="popLogFile"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnLogFile}" Placement="Custom"
           HorizontalOffset="0" VerticalOffset="0"
           StaysOpen="False"
           MouseLeftButtonDown="popLogFile_MouseLeftButtonDown">
```

3) Remove method btnLogFile_MouseEnter

Comment: thank you for the helpful comments. However, the first solution doesn't keep the popup open to edit the textbox. The second solution still gives me the same issue, namely that the popup behaves as I want it until I toggle the button. After that it simply refuses to appear.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand that should remain open. Please, Let me know if that works... I have no way to try it here now

Comment: Great, Now, I will update the answer. This is not a good solution, it was just to give the problem XD

Comment: Bad solution that uses code to manipulate UI Elements. If somebody wants to change the UI later, they will have this tightly coupled code to maintain as well.

Comment: Also note that if you manipulate a bound `DependencyProperty` in code, the binding is broken and the property value will no longer be updated with values from the binding source.

Comment: Can you read? ... Please read reviews. I have said that is a bad solution and that would be passed over ...

Comment: Oh.. I apologize, I didn't refresh the browser to see that comment.

Comment: I voted it as answer because it did solve my main problem (namely being able to send the project for testing). I now updated my code with these triggers and works like a charm. Very much obliged.

Answer (score 4):

Do not use code to manipulate UIElements. Bind the `IsOpen` Property of the Popup to the `IsMouseOver` property of the togglebutton. Or else if you need multiple or more complex conditions, set a `Style` to the Popup and in the style you can include `Triggers` or `DataTriggers`. I suggest you take a look at this [WPF Tutorial](http://www.wpftutorial.net/)

Edit:

Should be something like:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=YourToggleButton}" Value="True">
   <Setter TargetName="ThePopup" Property="IsOpen" Value="True"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: I agree that using styles is by far preferable to using code. I know about binding and triggers, but I do not see what conditions to implement to get the desired behaviour, namely opening the popup on IsMouseOver, keeping it open so I can edit the content until I click somewhere outside the popup. If you had an idea on what combination of triggers/conditions would do the job I'd be very much obliged.

Comment: The 'clicking anywhere else and have the popup closed' is by default when you set `StaysOpen=False`, and for the DataTrigger see my edit

Answer (score 1):

You can bind Popup.IsOpen and ToggleButton.IsChecked to the same bool property. See demo code here. http://bit.ly/L5jxFl